# How to parse only one part of a parsed json

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests

The site im parsing: https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/Markets/GetMarketSummaries
Im trying to make it so that i only parse one 'MarketName' which is chosen by the user, and then after the user chooses it it pulls the corresponding info from 'Summary' like High: Last: Low: Volume:, etc.
My Code Right Now:

```
r = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/Markets/GetMarketSummaries').text
data = json.loads(r)
for item in data['result']:
    CurrencyName = (item['Market']['MarketName'])
    print(CurrencyName)
for item in data['result']:
    LastPrice = (item['Summary']['Last'])
    print(LastPrice)
```

This pulls every 'MarketName' from the entire api, and every 'Last' price from every currency, how would i make it pull only the one that the user wanted / choose.

Comment: Have you written any of this or is it put together by asking a question on SO each step of the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v2.0/pub/Markets/GetMarketSummaries').text
data = json.loads(r)
for item in data['result']:
    if(item['Market']['MarketName'] == "USER_INPUT_HERE"):
       LastPrice = (item['Summary']['Last'])
       print(LastPrice)
```

This will only print the last price for the chosen market.

Comment: Glad it worked! Consider accepting the answer if it helped :)